# How to iterate over each edge of a complete graph exactly once?

Tags: c++, for-loop, graph

I want to set weight of all edges in complete graph ([a][b] = [b][a] = random integer). To do so, I wrote this piece of code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            w = std::rand() % 58 + 3;
            cout << i << ":" << j << " weight " << w << endl;
            graph[i][j] = graph[j][i] = w;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `n` is the number of vertices. Unfortunately, this isn't doing what I want. I'm trying to assign exactly one weight to each edge, but this code assigns two weights to most edges. For example, here's a sample output from the above code with `n` = 4:

```
0:1
0:2
0:3
1:2
1:3
2:1
2:3
3:1
3:2
```

Notice that both 0:3 and 3:0 are listed, so there will be two different weights on the edge. I'd like to just list these edges instead:

```
0:1
0:2
0:3
1:2
1:3
2:3
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: *but something's wrong with my for* What happens that makes you think it's wrong? What's the issue?

Comment: Your question is irrelevant to any future intention you have of using the resulting graph for Prim's algorithm or anything else.

Comment: @scohe001 I added more information

Comment: @Saibamen I reworded your question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do what you're trying to do - to iterate over all pairs without any repetition - is to change the indices on the for loops like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) // <--- Change here
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

This will properly loop over all pairs of distinct nodes exactly once. It does so by forcing the first component of the pair to be less than the second.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You :) How simple it was :D

Comment: I believe there is an error in the first line, it should be `for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)`.

Comment: @wintermute You could put the -1 there, but it’s not necessary. The inner loop won’t run if i = n - 1.